# Cannot find the file specified - java

Tags: java, input, output, inputstream

I have built a java program that takes input through

```
Scanner scan = null;
scan = new Scanner(system.in);
```

It then outputs what i want. The problem is I am trying to run the program through cmd.

> using javac Problem110102.java
>
> java Problem110102 < text.txt > output.txt

But i am getting "The system cannot find the file specified" even though both the text and output file are in the src folder with the .java file. I had another program that worked in cmd this one just doesn't want to. The program compiles perfectly fine and runs when i use the below but not when im trying to take in from a file.

> java Problem110102

Comment: yes its created in the same directory when i do javac

Comment: Make sure `text.txt` is where you think it is; also worth noting is that it should be `System.in` and that capitalization matters.

Comment: I have it as System.in in the program and all the file are in the same folder src

Comment: What platform is this? Also, please post the results of a `dir` or `ls` (whichever is appropriate).

Comment: Figured out the problem, I had the names text.txt and output.txt so i had to input java Problem110102 < text.txt.txt > ouput.txt.txt I have fixed it so it works as java Problem110102 < text.txt < output.txt